# In CloudWatch dashboard, how to include metric search in formula/sum

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to set up a CloudWatch dashboard to monitor total S3 storage usage. I can add each BucketSizeBytes metric, and then use an equation `SUM(METRICS())`, and see the total, but if I use a `SEARCH()` to include all the `MetricName="BucketSizeBytes"`, the `SUM()` doesn't return any value. Is there something else I need to add to my formula or search to get this to work?

This is probably easier to explain with a screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out. You have to put the `SEARCH()` inside the `SUM()`, i.e.

```
SUM(SEARCH('{AWS/S3,BucketName,StorageType} MetricName="BucketSizeBytes"', 'Average', 300))
```